# how to show the id of a particular id from clicking the detail button from the table

Tags: javascript, node.js

As i am learning node.js it is new to me so i need some help learning it and i am facing a lot of problems.

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/**
 parse all data
**/
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
/**
 used for date format
**/
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();
/**
 used for template
**/
app.set('view enjine', 'ejs');

/**

 used for date format
**/
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname+ '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname+ '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname+ '/node_modules/jquery/dist'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname+ '/node_modules/tether/dist/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname+ '/public/assets/css'));
app.use('/fonts', express.static(__dirname+'./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts'));
app.use('/static', express.static('./node_modules/font-awesome/css'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use('/vendor', express.static(__dirname + "/vendor"));


const baseURL="http://127.0.0.1:8080";
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'my_db'
});
con.connect(console.log('database connected'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 con.query('SELECT * FROM student_info', function (error, results) {
   if (error) throw error;
   console.log('The solution is: ', results);
 });
 res.render('./pages/index.ejs');
});
app.get('/form',function(req,res){
 res.render('./pages/form.ejs');
});
app.post('/form',function(req,res){
 console.log(req.body);
 var insertEventData = {
    s_id:req.body.s_id,
    student_name:req.body.student_name,
    blood_group:req.body.blood_group,
    d_birth:req.body.d_birth,
    religion:req.body.religion,
    tel_number:req.body.tel_number,
    image: req.body.image,
    father_name:req.body.father_name,
    mother_name:req.body.mother_name,
    f_occupation:req.body.f_occupation,
    m_occupation:req.body.m_occupation,
    f_income:req.body.f_income,
    g_tel:req.body.g_tel,
    g_name:req.body.g_name,
    v_name:req.body.v_name,
    strt_name:req.body.strt_name,
    post_office:req.body.post_office,
    thana_name:req.body.thana_name,
    tel_num:req.body.tel_num,
    p_village:req.body.p_village,
    p_street:req.body.p_street,
    p_post:req.body.p_post,
    p_thana:req.body.p_thana,
    p_district:req.body.p_district,
    exam_name:req.body.exam_name,
    department:req.body.department,
    board_name:req.body.board_name,
    i_name:req.body.i_name,
    roll_number:req.body.roll_number,
    session:req.body.session,
    exam_center:req.body.exam_center,
    passing_year:req.body.passing_year,
    gpa_number:req.body.gpa_number,
    gpa_num:req.body.gpa_num,
   };
   con.query("INSERT INTO student_info SET ? ", insertEventData , function(err,result){
    if(err)
     throw err;
    res.redirect(baseURL);
   });
});
app.get('/table',function(req,res){
 con.query("SELECT `s_id`, `student_name`,`roll_number` FROM `student_info`", function (error, result) {
  console.log(result);
     res.render('./pages/table.ejs',{
      items : result
     });
 });
});
app.get('/details/:s_id',function(req,res){
 con.query('SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE s_id = ?',req.params.s_id, function (error, results) {
   if (error) throw error;
   console.log('details: ', results);
 });
 res.render('./pages/details.ejs',{
  item : results
 });
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log('you are on server 8080');
```

When i am clicking the detail button in the table how to show the deatil of that student in another page called details.ejs. it will be helpful if anyone suggest me some mysql query to show the the id of the student in the route also.

```html
<% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
 <div class="page-wrapper">
            <% include ../partials/sidenav.ejs %>
        <!-- PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="page-container2">
            <% include ../partials/topnav.ejs %>
            <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="table-responsive table--no-card m-b-30">
                                  <% if(items.length > 0){ %>
                                    <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                                <th>Roll Number</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        
                                        <tbody>
                                          <% items.forEach(function(item,table){ %>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><%= table+1 %></td>
                                                <td><%= item.student_name %></td>
                                                <td><%= item.roll_number %></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="details" class="btn btn-success">Details</a>
                                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                                </td>  
                                            </tr>
                                            <% }); %>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <% }else{ %>
                                    <p><strong>There is no element in the database</strong></p>
                                    <% } %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <section>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="copyright">
                                        <p>Copyright © 2018 Utshab. All rights reserved. Template by <a href="https://Utshab.net">Utshab</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

here is my github repo 
https://github.com/Nodeboy28/JMCS-database.git